# How can I configure Visual Studio as the default CMake generator?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2022

I have configured Visual Studio to use CMakePresets.json for CMake settings, not CMakeSettings.json:
[image]

My CMakePresets.json does not explicitly specify any generator:

```
{
  "version": 3,
  "cmakeMinimumRequired": {
    "major": 3,
    "minor": 20,
    "patch": 0
  },
  "configurePresets": [
    {
      "name": "base",
      "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/build"
    },
    {
      "name": "vcpkg",
      "inherits": "base",
      "description": "Use VCPKG toolchain file from default location ../../vcpkg/",
      "toolchainFile": "${sourceDir}/../../vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
    },
    {
      "name": "clangcl",
      "inherits": "base",
      "description": "Use ClangCL toolchain",
      "toolset": "ClangCL"
    },
    {
      "name": "vcpkg-clangcl",
      "description": "Useful for Windows builds: use ClangCL toolchain and VCPKG toolchain file from default location ../../vcpkg/",
      "inherits": [
        "clangcl",
        "vcpkg"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

When I configure the cache from the Visual Studio IDE, the CMake output reveals that CMake has been invoked with the Ninja generator:

```
1> Command line: "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe" /c "%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\chcp.com 65001 >NUL && "c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\enterprise\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\cmake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"  -G "Ninja"  -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE:FILEPATH="C:/dev/project/app/../../vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"   -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\enterprise\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\cmake\Ninja\ninja.exe" "C:\dev\project\app" 2>&1"
```

**How can I configure Visual Studio (2022) to choose "Visual Studio 17 2022" as the default generator instead of Ninja?**

---

As a matter of comparison, when I configure the cache from the VS 2022 Developer Command Prompt, the default generator is Visual Studio 17 2022:

```
> cmake --preset vcpkg-clangcl
Preset CMake variables:

  CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE:FILEPATH="C:/dev/project/app/../../vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"

-- Building for: Visual Studio 17 2022
...
```